# AutoMapper: Collection to Single string Property

Tags: automapper

I have a scenario in which I have to do following mapping

```cs
public class Company : BaseEntity
{            
    public string Name { get; set; }    
    public virtual ICollection<CompanyService> CompanyServices { get; set; }
}
public class Service : BaseEntity
{         
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<CompanyService> CompanyServices { get; set; }    
}
public class CompanyService : BaseEntity
{
    public long CompanyID { get; set; }
    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }

    public long ServiceID { get; set; }
    public virtual Service Service { get; set; }    
}
```

And corresponding View Models

```cs
public class CompanyViewModel : BaseEntity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Services { get; set; }
}
public class ServiceViewModel : BaseEntity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class CompanyServiceViewModel : BaseEntity
{
    public string ServiceName { get; set; }
}
```

I want to Map using AutoMapper in which I should get Service's Name as comma separated string in CompanyViewModel class

```cs
Mapper.CreateMap<Company, CompanyViewModel>();
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the following mapping:

```cs
Mapper.CreateMap<Company, CompanyViewModel>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Services,
         m => m.MapFrom(src => string.Join(", ", src.CompanyServices
                                                    .Select (s => s.Service.Name))));
```

But note that you won't be able to use the mapping in an `IQueryable` for LINQ to Entities directly, because EF will throw an exception that it can't convert the `string.Join` part into SQL. You'll have to use `AsEnumerable` and then do the mapping, like:

```cs
Mapper.Map<T>(context.Entities.AsEnumerable(). ...)
```

Comment: This answer helped me. But do you have an example of what you mean with the AsEnumerable? I've already encountered that it doesn't work with an IQueryable

Comment: very helpful tks