# How can I create a comma delimited string using Linq object graph navigation?

Tags: c#, string, linq, dapper

```
public class PatientViewModel
{
    public int PID { get; set; } 
    public string patientname { get; set; } 
    public virtual ICollection<Patient_VisitHistoryViewModel> Patient_VisitHistoryViewModelList { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Patient_insurancecompaniesViewModel> Patient_insurancecompaniesViewModelList { get; set; }
}

public class Patient_VisitHistoryViewModel
{
    public int VID { get; set; } 
    public string visitstudylist { get; set; }
    public string visttype { get; set; } 
}

public class Patient_insurancecompaniesViewModel
{
    public int PINSID { get; set; } 
    public int PID { get; set; } 
    public int INSID { get; set; } 
    public string insurancecompanyname { get; set; }
}

public class Patient
{
    public int PID { get; set; } // PID (Primary key)
    public string patientname { get; set; } // patientname (length: 100)
        
    // Reverse navigation
    public virtual ICollection<Patient_insurancecompanies> Patient_insurancecompanies { get; set; } // Patient_insurancecompanies.FK_Patient_insurancecompanies_Patient
    public virtual ICollection<Visit> Visit { get; set; } // Visit.FK_Visit_Patient
}


public class Visit
{
    public int VID { get; set; } // VID (Primary key)
    public int PID { get; set; } // PID
    // Reverse navigation
    public virtual ICollection<Visit_studiesperformed> Visit_studiesperformed { get; set; } // Visit_studiesperformed.FK_visits_studiesperformed_visits

    // Foreign keys
    public virtual Branch Branch { get; set; } // FK_visits_branches
    public virtual Patient Patient { get; set; } // FK_Visit_Patient
    public virtual Visittype Visittype { get; set; } // FK_Visit_Visittype
}

public class Visit_studiesperformed
{
    public int VSPID { get; set; } // VSPID (Primary key)
    public int VID { get; set; } // VID
    public int STID { get; set; } // STID

    // Reverse navigation
    public virtual ICollection<Visit_studiesperformed_medicalreport> Visit_studiesperformed_medicalreport { get; set; } // Visit_studiesperformed_medicalreport.FK_visits_medicalreport_visits_studiesperformed

    // Foreign keys
    public virtual Studies Studies { get; set; } // FK_Visit_studiesperformed_studies
    public virtual Visit Visit { get; set; } // FK_visits_studiesperformed_visits
}

public class Studies
{
    public int STID { get; set; } // STID (Primary key)
    public string studydescription { get; set; } // studydescription (length: 100)

    // Reverse navigation
    public virtual ICollection<Visit_studiesperformed> Visit_studiesperformed { get; set; } // Visit_studiesperformed.FK_Visit_studiesperformed_studies
}

public class Insurancecompany
{
    public int INSID { get; set; } // INSID (Primary key)
    public string insurancecompanyname { get; set; } // insurancecompanyname (length: 100)

    // Reverse navigation
    public virtual System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<Patient_insurancecompanies> Patient_insurancecompanies { get; set; } // Patient_insurancecompanies.FK_Patient_insurancecompanies_Insurancecompany
}

public ActionResult Edit(int PID)
{
    Patient patient = bLLPatient.GetPatientByPID(PID);
  
    List<Insurancecompany> ListOfInsuranceCompany = bLLControltables.GetList_Insurancecompany();
    List<Studies> ListofStudies = bLLControltables.GetList_Studies();

    PatientViewModel patientViewModel = mapper.Map<PatientViewModel>(patient);
    patientViewModel.Patient_insurancecompaniesViewModelList.ToList().ForEach(x => x.insurancecompanyname = ListOfInsuranceCompany.Where(b => x.INSID == b.INSID).SingleOrDefault().insurancecompanyname);
   
    return View(patientViewModel);
}
```

Look at the bottom where I have `public ActionResult Edit(int PID)`.  I am trying to make a comma delimited list of `Studies.studydescription` and store in int the List `patientViewModel.Patient_VisitHistoryViewModelList.visitstudylist`...

I have managed to get something similar done with the field `patientViewModel.Patient_insurancecompaniesViewModelList` with this code

```
patientViewModel.Patient_insurancecompaniesViewModelList.ToList().ForEach(x => x.insurancecompanyname = ListOfInsuranceCompany.Where(b => x.INSID == b.INSID).SingleOrDefault().insurancecompanyname);
```

So what I have to do is:
Enumerate `Patient_VisitHistoryViewModelList`, get each visit and for each visit get each `Visit_studiesperformed` and for each `Vist_studyperformed` get each `studies.studydescription`....

Then somehow make a comma delimited string and store it in each `patientViewModel.Patient_insurancecompaniesViewModelList.visitstudylist`

I did manage to come across a way to make the comma delimited list here [AutoMapper: Collection to Single string Property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23816068/automapper-collection-to-single-string-property) but i am having problems putting it together.

Comment: If this will create comma-separated values in a single column in the database, you should go back to the drawing board and find a way to avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

You need an array of strings to use Join, not Single.  Try something like this :

```
string results = String.Join(",",patientViewModel.Patient_insurancecompaniesViewModelList.ToList().ForEach(x => x.insurancecompanyname = ListOfInsuranceCompany.Where(b => x.INSID == b.INSID).Select(y => y.insurancecompanyname).ToArray());
```

Comment: this gets my halfway with the comma delimited string but i am still having problems navigating through the object model.  I left out your contribution in the below.. patientViewModel.Patient_VisitHistoryViewModelList.ToList().ForEach(x => x.visitstudylist = patient.Visit.ToList().ForEach(y => y.Visit_studiesperformed.ToList().ForEach(z => z.Studies.studydescription.ToString()));    Getting error cannot implicitly convert void to string....

Comment: It looks like some of the properties are null. Using ToString() is going to give erorrs when items are null.  Try this instead :  string results = String.Join(",",patientViewModel.Patient_insurancecompaniesViewModelList.ToList().ForEach(x => x.insurancecompanyname = ListOfInsuranceCompany.Where(b => (x.INSID == b.INSID) && (x.insurancecompanyname != null)).Select(y => (string)y.insurancecompanyname).ToArray());

Answer (score 0):

```
patientViewModel.Patient_VisitHistoryViewModelList
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(x => x.visitstudylist = String.Join(", ", patient.Visit
        .Single(b => b.VID == x.VID).Visit_studiesperformed
        .Where(m => m.status == "Active")
        .ToList()
        .Select(w => ListofStudies
            .Where(b => w.STID == b.STID)
            .SingleOrDefault().studydescription)));
```

Above is the solution.