# "Missing map from System.Char to System.String" AutoMapper error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datatables, automapper

I'm trying to map my `Box` object to my `BoxedElectrodesRowModel`.

The `Box` object has a property `SerialNumbers`, and each of *those* has its own property of `SerialNumberName`. I'm trying to map that list of `SerialNumberName`s to a list of strings in my `BoxedElectrodeRowModel` called `SerialNumbers`.

**AutoMapper code**

```
c.CreateMap<Box, BoxedElectrodesRowModel>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.BoxId, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.BoxID))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.SerialNumbers, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.SerialNumbers.Select(t => t.SerialNumberName).FirstOrDefault().ToList()))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.DateCreated, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.DateCreated));
```

Here's the error I'm getting now. I don't know what "characters" it's referring to.

> Missing map from System.Char to System.String. Create using
>   Mapper.CreateMap

The purpose of all of this is to create a table using DataTables that displays each `Box` with a list of its `SerialNumbers` on each row, if that helps. Everything is coded, but I keep getting the above error when it's run.

**Edit:** Here are my classes I'm mapping. I'm trying to map `BoxId` to `BoxId`, `DateCreated` to `DateCreated`, and the `SerialNumberName` from each `SerialNumber` (in a list) to `SerialNumbers`.

**Box** (Autogenerated)

```
public partial class Box
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Box()
    {
        this.SerialNumbers = new HashSet<SerialNumber>();
    }

    public int BoxID { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> DateShipped { get; set; }
    public string TrackingNumber { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> DateReceived { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<SerialNumber> SerialNumbers { get; set; }
}
```

**SerialNumber** (This is a property of each 'Box', also autogenerated code)

```
public partial class SerialNumber
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public SerialNumber()
    {
        this.Comments = new HashSet<Comment>();
        this.WIPHistories = new HashSet<WIPHistory>();
    }

    public int SerialNumberID { get; set; }
    public int IncomingLotID { get; set; }
    public string SerialNumberName { get; set; }
    public string LamPurchaseOrder { get; set; }
    public string LamLineNumber { get; set; }
    public bool Refurbished { get; set; }
    public int WIPLocationID { get; set; }
    public int StatusID { get; set; }
    public int RouteSectionStepID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> RejectCategoryID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> BoxID { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
    public virtual IncomingLot IncomingLot { get; set; }
    public virtual RejectCategory RejectCategory { get; set; }
    public virtual Status Status { get; set; }
    public virtual WIPLocation WIPLocation { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<WIPHistory> WIPHistories { get; set; }
    public virtual Box Box { get; set; }
    public virtual RouteSectionStep RouteSectionStep { get; set; }
}
```

**BoxedElectrodesRowModel**

```
public class BoxedElectrodesRowModel
{
    public int BoxId { get; set; }
    public List<string> SerialNumbers { get; set; } // change from List to ICollection if there are problems
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> DateCreated { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Can you please post definition of your Box and BoxedElectrodesRowModel classes? At list show properties which you are mapping

Comment: Added the classes I'm mapping

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is `FirstOrDefault()` call. Because it returns only first `string` from serial number names. But string is `IEnumerable<char>`. When AutoMapper sees two enumerables, it tries to map them. In your case it will be `IEnumerable<char>` to `IEnumerable<string>`.

To fix this problem remove `FirstOrDefault()` call. Also thus AutoMapper knows how to map `IEnumerable<T>` to `List<T>` you don't need to create list manually.

```
opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.SerialNumbers.Select(t => t.SerialNumberName))
```

Comment: This gets me a bit further, but now I have this error: "DbSortClause expressions must have a type that is order comparable.
Parameter name: key". I got this error before as well, I think adding "FirstOrDefault" was supposed to solve it

Comment: @NathanR this error is related to `OrderBy` call to database. But I don't see such code in your mapping. You are doing `OrderBy` somewhere else?

Comment: See Edit 2 at the bottom, I added the code where the latest error is occurring.

Comment: @NathanR I rolled back your edit, because it shows completely different problem not related to *“Missing map from System.Char to System.String” AutoMapper error* as title of your question says. I suggest you to create another question with code related to queryable extensions usage and new error which you have now

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is highlighted in the error message.

Automapper is being told to map from a character object, System.Char, to a string object, System.String.

I believe the culprit is the call to FirstOrDefault(), which when called on a string, will return the first Char in the string:

src.SerialNumbers.Select(t => t.SerialNumberName).FirstOrDefault().ToList()

The select statement selects a String from the 'SerialNumbers' collection, which is what the 'MapFrom' call needs...so you don't need to call .FirstOrDefault or .ToList().

Remove them and see how this goes:

```
c.CreateMap<Box, BoxedElectrodesRowModel>()
.ForMember(dest => dest.BoxId, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.BoxID))
.ForMember(dest => dest.SerialNumbers, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.SerialNumbers.Select(t => t.SerialNumberName)))
.ForMember(dest => dest.DateCreated, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.DateCreated));
```

There is also another post about this issue:

[AutoMapper: Collection to Single string Property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23816068/automapper-collection-to-single-string-property)

Comment: I'm now getting the error "DbSortClause expressions must have a type that is order comparable. Parameter name: key"